# How does one find and replace text in all open files with geany?

Tags: text-processing, editors, geany

How does one find and replace text in **all open files** with [geany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Menu `Search->Replace` (or `Ctrl+h`). Fill in find and replace boxes, expand `Replace All`, click `In Session`

## Step-by-step:

### Select "Replace" from Search menu.

[image: Select "Replace" from Search menu.]

### Expand "Replace All"

[image: Expand "Replace All"]

### Click "In Session"

[image: Click "In Session"]